# Voltage reference for comparator

Tags: comparator, voltage-reference

I need reference for comparator and considering option between using one made from voltage divider and the one from precision reference.

Basically, if i were to use voltage divider, it will be simple voltage divider dividing voltage from voltage regulator.

As it is used for zero-crossing detector for timing critical application, the stability and noise performance is very important.

Can I expect a significant advantage from using precision reference in my application?

Comment: You don't need a reference at all to detect zero, so there must be a more to your application (especially some numbers) then is in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I expect a significant advantage from using precision reference in my application?

Yes. The power supply rejection and stability of a precision voltage reference will be, by design, much superior to a voltage regulator. If not, you've got a rubbish voltage reference.

No, will it be useful/necessary?

Without knowing more about your situation, it's not clear. You need to determine exactly how much noise you can tolerate and how much stability you require. As long as your regulator is relatively stable, a voltage regulator and a decoupling cap should be sufficient for most applications.